# Error for i in request.body: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Tags: python, json, api

This isnt's my code, I'm just a beginner in programing and it's for the course. I can't call API to analyze photo, I find error in this line:

```
response =requests.post(address, headers=headers, params=parameters, data=image_data)
```

Just can't solve it.

```
# This code will show you how to call the Computer Vision API from Python

# You can find documentation on the Computer Vision Analyze Image method here
# https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa
# Use the requests library to simplify making a REST API call from Python 

import requests

# We will need the json library to read the data passed back 
# by the web service
import json

# You need to update the SUBSCRIPTION_KEY to 
# they key for your Computer Vision Service
SUBSCRIPTION_KEY = "****************************"

# You need to update the vision_service_address to the address of
# your Computer Vision Service
vision_service_address = "https://pythonimageanalyzerr.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"
# Add the name of the function you want to call to the address
address = vision_service_address + "vision/v3.0/analyze"

# According to the documentation for the analyze image function 
# There are three optional parameters: language, details & visualFeatures

parameters  = {'visualFeatures':'Description,Color',
               'language':'en'}

# Open the image file to get a file object containing the image to analyze
image_path = "./TestImages/PolarBear.jpg"
image_data = open(image_path, "rb").read

# According to the documentation for the analyze image function
# we need to specify the subscription key and the content type
# in the HTTP header. Content-Type is application/octet-stream when you pass in a image directly
headers    = {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
              'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': SUBSCRIPTION_KEY}

# According to the documentation for the analyze image function
# we use HTTP POST to call this function

response =requests.post(address, headers=headers, params=parameters, data=image_data)

# Raise an exception if the call returns an error code
response.raise_for_status()

# Display the JSON results returned
results = response.json()
print(json.dumps(results))
```

And here are the errors I find:

> ```sh
> File "e:/programming/API.py", line 42, in <module>
>    response =requests.post(address, headers=headers, params=parameters, data=image_data)
>    for i in request.body:
> TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable>
> ```

Comment: Code in error message is not there in the question

Comment: I think parantheses are missing. You need an object not a method as parameter. Pass the result of the function call instead of the function itself.
eg.  'image_data = open(image_path, "rb").read' should be with parantheses  'image_data = open(image_path, "rb").read()'
or

response =requests.post(address, headers=headers, params=parameters, data=image_data() )

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in line 31.
Replace

```
image_data = open(image_path, "rb").read
```

with

```
image_data = open(image_path, "rb").read()
```